# Scoping in r2d3 visualization - d3.selectAll vs svg.selectAll

Tags: r, d3.js, r2d3

Why does `d3.selectAll('rect')...` not work as seen in the script below in the mouseover function, but `svg.selectAll('rect')...` does?

`svg` is the special pre-set selector from r2d3.

Additionally, I have noticed that running e.g. `d3.selectAll('rect').remove()` from the browser console does not work when running the visualization from Rstudio.

This is from the r2d3 example, as `sample.js`:

```
// !preview r2d3 data=c(0.3, 0.6, 0.8, 0.95, 0.40, 0.20)

var barHeight = Math.floor(height / data.length);

svg.selectAll('rect')
  .data(data)
  .enter().append('rect')
    .attr('width', function(d) { return d * width; })
    .attr('height', barHeight)
    .attr('y', function(d, i) { return i * barHeight; })
    .attr('fill', 'steelblue')
    .on('mouseover', function(d){
      d3.select(this).attr('fill', 'red')
      
      //svg.selectAll('rect').attr('fill', 'red')
      d3.selectAll('rect').attr('fill', 'red')
      
    })
```

Run from R via `r2d3::r2d3("sample.js", data=c(0.3, 0.6, 0.8, 0.95, 0.40, 0.20))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default r2d3 places the visualization in a shadow DOM. Both d3.select and d3.selectAll start their search at the root element of the DOM, but do not venture into a shadow DOM's child nodes.

Neither select nor selectAll will cross into a shadow tree from the current tree being searched. As `svg` is a selection of an element within the shadow DOM, the rectangles can be found with `svg.selectAll("rect")` but not `d3.selectAll("rect")` (the rects aren't "shadowed" relative to the SVG).

The easiest solution is to not create a shadow DOM by setting the r2d3 shadow option to false.

eg (using the [base example](https://rstudio.github.io/r2d3/articles/introduction.html#d3-scripts) from r2d3's documentation):

```
r2d3(options(r2d3.shadow = FALSE), data=c(0.3, 0.6, 0.8, 0.95, 0.40, 0.20), script = "barchart.js")
```

Of course in doing so you lose the encapsulation offered by the shadow root, but this might be preferable or neutral depending on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that sometimes the r2d3.shadow option doesn't always work well, so here's another possible solution. The parent of the event target will be the svg/g that you've placed it in.

```
// !preview r2d3 data=c(0.3, 0.6, 0.8, 0.95, 0.40, 0.20)

var barHeight = Math.floor(height / data.length);

svg.selectAll('rect')
  .data(data)
  .enter().append('rect')
    .attr('width', function(d) { return d * width; })
    .attr('height', barHeight)
    .attr('y', function(d, i) { return i * barHeight; })
    .attr('fill', 'steelblue')
    .on('mouseover', function(d){
      const parent = d3.select(d.target.parentElement); // this is the original svg
      
      
      //svg.selectAll('rect').attr('fill', 'red')
      parent.selectAll('rect').attr('fill', 'blue')
      d3.select(this).attr('fill', 'red')
      
    })
```